# Рабочий Pull To Refresh

Tags: android, github, eclipse, pulltorefresh

Здравствуйте, скиньте, пожалуйста, РАБОЧИЙ проект с PullToRefresh от [link text](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh). Я скачиваю проект с GitHub, открываю его и сразу же выскакивают ошибки. Может быть, я делаю что-то не так?
P.S. Проблема с ошибками у проектов возникает почти всегда. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно импортировать их с GitHub в Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте стандартный андроидовский [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html).

Comment: Мне он не нравится

Comment: @Andrach, чем же, интересно?

Comment: Он не такой гибкий в настройке, как ptr от chrisbanes.